# 2D Array Scores

Tags: java

This is the original prompt:

Write program that declares a 2-dimensional array of doubles called scores with three rows and three columns. Use a nested while loop to get the nine (3 x 3) doubles from the user at the command line. Finally, use a nested for loop to compute the average of the doubles in each row and output these three averages to the command line.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scorer {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    double [][] scores = new double[3][3];
    double value = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j;

    while (i < 3) {

        j = 0;

        while (j < 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            value = scnr.nextDouble();
            scores[i][j] = value;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    int average = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < scores[i].length; j++) {
            average += value;
            value = value / scores[i][j];
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

}

}
```

The part that I need help on is the nested for loop at the bottom of the code. This code is supposed to compute the average of the numbers that are entered; however, I am confused on how to do that with the nested for loop.

Answer (score 2):

you're almost there!
Here are the things you need to do:

1)you've to initialize the variable 'average' after the first for loop.
because average needs to be 0 i.e., reset after second for loop ends each time.

2)you've defined "value = value / scores[i][j]" . I don't know why you did that, but "value = scores[i][j]" must solve your problem.

3) you should print the average only thrice i.e., after calculating average of each row. so, print average at the end of second for loop.

Hope this makes it clear.
here's the code for your reference:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int average = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        value = scores[i][j];
        average += value;           
    }
        System.out.println(average/3);       
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can format it so that it says the row number and then has the three numbers that you entered in that row and then the same for the other two rows?

Comment: yes, assign each row to another three 1D arrays. First,create three 1D arrays.Then,write each row into each one of the 3 1D arrays in the same for loop where you've calculated average and then play with those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Ever `i` represents a row, every `j` represents a column.

You need the average of every row, meaning that for every same `i` and every different `j` for that `i` you need to store the values and calculate the average.

Looks like homework code. We can give you hints but not write it for you :(